# jQuery questions that I came across while learning (beginner)

Tags: jquery

1. what is domEle in this example? I can see an explanation in jQuery.com - jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) ), but still is hard to understand for me what is "valueOfElement"? Can anybody clear a bit this for me?

   ```
   $("button").click(function () {
     $("div").each(function (index, domEle) {
       $(domEle).css("backgroundColor", "yellow"); 
       if ($(this).is("#stop")) {
         $("span").text("Stopped at div index #" + index);
         return false;
       }
     });
   });
   ```
2. if I will write like this: `$("input[name='newsletter']").next().text(" is newsletter");`  jquery will find only exact match and if I write like this: `$("input[name$='newsletter']").next().text(" is newsletter");` jquery will find exact match and lets say value of "newsletters" too?
3. Author uses this code:

   ```
   $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
               if($(e.target).parent("a.signin").length==0) {
                   $(".signin").removeClass("menu-open");
                   $("fieldset#signin_menu").hide();
               }
           });
   ```

   to hide the drop down whenever user presses anywhere else on the document. Can anybody comment on this line   `if($(e.target).parent("a.signin").length==0) {` as I do not fully understand what we are doing in here. Original article in here: http://aext.net/2009/08/perfect-sign-in-dropdown-box-likes-twitter-with-jquery/
4. A default method call that I should be aware of?

In one of the tutorials I found such comment:

"Finally, if we don’t include a margin in the CSS, the result of the CSS method call is auto, which won’t parse properly, so we need to replace the text “auto” with the number 0"

```
var top = $('#comment').offset().top - parseFloat($('#comment').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/,0));
```

Can anybody comment on this as I do not fully understand what he is doing in here.

Original article in here: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

Comment: You should break your array of questions in individual questions. Each question will have it's own set of answers. You will hardly get a decent answer asking a bulk of questions this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) $("div") will select every div on the page. Each will iterate through all of those divs. For each iteration, domEle will be a reference to the div that the loop is currently iterating over.

2.) ^= is what you're looking for, ^= searches for all starting with the given string. $= searches for all ending with the given string: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

3.) e.target is where the user clicked. .parent("a.signin").length==0 selects the parent if it is an anchor with class .signin. Checking length equal to zero is equivalent to asking if anything was selected. So basically if the user didn't click within an anchor of class signin, then do something.

4.) $('#comment').offset().top gets the offset from the top of the #comment element. parseFloat($('#comment').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/,0)) gets the margin from the top of the element. If the margin is set as "auto" it considers the margin to be 0. Parsefloat ensures that it is handled as a number, it is then subtracted from the top offset. This is custom code, not something you'll use/need often.

Answer (score 1):

1) It is the iteration element - the element currently being handled by `each`. It is automatically forwarded to the callback. (I don't like this model; personally I prefer to use `$(this)` inside `each` callbacks).

2) The first finds an element whose `name` attribute is exactly `newsletter`, while the latter finds an element whose `name` attribute *ends with* `newsletter`. The use of `$` is a borrow from regular expression grammar. (Regular expressions are an entirely separate topic).

3) This is an example of event delegation (though not a very good one - jQuery can handle this much more effectively than this example shows). Event delegation is definitely something to look into.

The line you mention interrogates the event's trigger element - the element that triggered the event - and checks its parent against a condition.

4) I wouldn't even spend any energy on this point - it's very non-standard and localised to a specific use-case.

Comment: +1 because you managed to answer all 4 questions at 4 close votes.. Anyway, I'd put an answer for Q4: It just stores the element's position relative to the top of the document minus its `marginTop`.

Comment: haha I was busy writing while the close votes were coming in. I don't personally have a problem with grouped questions (they were very small) but I know some people disagree.